# Oracle SQL query to list all active users/schemas and give object count

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, inline

I am trying to write a query that will give me information on users/schemas.

It would need to use the following:

COLUMNS = username, default_tablespace, account_status 
TABLE = dba_users

PLUS, a new virtual column in the result set showing an object count for that username/schema. i.e. the number of objects owned by it.
The simple where clauses should be that the account_status is open, and that the username is not one of X, Y, Z.

So it will be somehow combining the below basic query:

```
select username, default_tablespace, account_status
from dba_users
where account_status = 'OPEN'
and username not in ('GEORGE','ANNA','BOB')
```

With this one:

```
select owner, count(*) as object_count from dba_objects
group by owner
order by 1
```

I tried to have a go at using in line queries. The best I could come up with was the below query, but this only lists users that exist in the dba_objects table. i.e. ONLY, lists schemas (contains at least 1 object) rather than plain users.

```
select username, account_status, default_tablespace, subquery1.object_count 
from dba_users,
(
select owner,count(*) as object_count from dba_objects
group by owner order by 1
) subquery1
where username = owner
and account_status = 'OPEN'
and username not in ('GEORGE','ANNA','BOB')
order by username
```

I think I need to perform a left outer join, to preserve the records from dba_users that fulfill the rest of the query, and would therefore return simply a "NULL" in the object_count column, but when I try this as below, I get garbage results where it lists out way too much, repeating users many times with random object counts.

```
select username, account_status, default_tablespace, subquery1.object_count 
from dba_users,
(
select owner, count(*) as object_count from dba_objects
group by owner order by 1
) subquery1
left join dba_users on username = subquery1.owner
and account_status = 'OPEN'
and username not in ('GEORGE','ANNA','BOB')
order by username
```

As a bonus, if someone can come up with a query that provides not only the above, but with an additional virtual column giving a size of tablespace used, that would be great. So it would use something like the below query:

select round((sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024),1) as size_in_gb, owner
   from dba_segments
   group by
   owner

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to structure such a query.  If you're only getting a single value from the other table, I'd be tempted to do an inline select rather than bothering to do an explicit join

```
select username, default_tablespace, account_status,
       (select count(1)
          from dba_objects o
         where o.owner = u.username) cnt_objects_owned,
       (select sum(bytes)
          from dba_segments s
         where s.owner = u.username) total_size_of_segments
  from dba_users u
 where account_status = 'OPEN'
   and username not in ('GEORGE','ANNA','BOB')
```

This has the advantage that it's relatively easy to add new inline selects.  It will be terribly inefficient, however, if in the future you want to get a number of values from `dba_objects` or `dba_segments` and you end up repeating yourself in other inline selects.

Interestingly, I keep getting errors posting if I change the `count(1)` in my query to a `count(*)`

Comment: I seem to have been over complicating it, (as usual) by trying to but the inline query in the from clause, rather than the initial select. Thank you very much, this achieves everything I require. And yes, it is slow...but hey. Thanks.